# rand::thread_rng() panicking

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I'm trying to generate a random number in a Near smart contract using Rust. However when I run this code:

```rust
    pub fn get_last(&self) -> u64 {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        println!("i32: {}, i32: {}", rng.gen::<i32>(), rng.gen::<i32>());
        return self.lastval;
    }
```

I've got this error message:

```
$ near view $ID get_last '{}'
View call: dev-1643558356736-93385541578458.get_last({})
An error occured
Error: Querying [object Object] failed: wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(HostError(GuestPanic { panic_msg: "panicked at 'internal error: entered unreachable code', C:\\Users\\GANSOR-PC\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\rand-0.4.6\\src\\jitter.rs:703:9" })).

----------------
jitter.rs:703:9

    #[cfg(all(target_arch = "wasm32", not(target_os = "emscripten")))]
    pub fn get_nstime() -> u64 {
        unreachable!()
    }
```

in lib.rs I have:

```rust
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
extern crate rand;
```

And in Cargo.toml I have:

```
[dependencies]
near-sdk = "3.1.0"
near-contract-standards = "3.1.1"
rand = "*"
```

So, where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you using `wasm-bindgen`? [This comment on github](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/issues/810#issuecomment-497930233) should help you.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use a typical random number generator since you are running inside of a virtual machine with no access to typical random seed generators like hardware clock or other machine data

instead consider using the provided random seed you can get through a couple of functions exposed on `env` like `env::random_seed` https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-sdk/src/environment/env.rs#L236-L254

```rs
/// Returns the random seed from the current block. This 32 byte hash is based on the VRF value from
/// the block. This value is not modified in any way each time this function is called within the
/// same method/block.
pub fn random_seed() -> Vec<u8> {
    random_seed_array().to_vec()
}

/// Returns the random seed from the current block. This 32 byte hash is based on the VRF value from
/// the block. This value is not modified in any way each time this function is called within the
/// same method/block.
pub fn random_seed_array() -> [u8; 32] {
    //* SAFETY: random_seed syscall will always generate 32 bytes inside of the atomic op register
    //*         so the read will have a sufficient buffer of 32, and can transmute from uninit
    //*         because all bytes are filled. This assumes a valid random_seed implementation.
    unsafe {
        sys::random_seed(ATOMIC_OP_REGISTER);
        read_register_fixed_32(ATOMIC_OP_REGISTER)
    }
}
```

here's an example

https://github.com/near-apps/coin-flip/blob/1476bbdf0fee3b6647766ee6e94e40254f728191/contracts/src/lib.rs#L50-L59

```rs
pub fn play(&mut self) -> u8 {
    let account_id = env::signer_account_id();
    let mut credits = self.credits.get(&account_id).unwrap_or(0);
    assert!(credits > 0, "no credits to play");
    credits = credits - ONE_NEAR;
    
    let rand: u8 = *env::random_seed().get(0).unwrap();
    if rand < PROB {
        credits = credits + 10 * ONE_NEAR;
    }

    self.credits.insert(&account_id, &credits);
    rand
}
```